# pass local credentials via SPNEGO / HTTP

Tags: node.js, http, electron, spnego

With web based applications running in Chrome, I have been able to leverage Chrome to negotiate passing local credentials via SPNEGO. In the XMLHttpRequest, we set the option pass *withCredentials*.  It seems like the **http** module in nodejs/electron does not have this capability.

Has anyone been able to pass the credentials of the currently logged in Windows user using the **http** module in electron?  I am looking to make calls to some internal web services that require authentication and I don't want to force the user to enter login credentials again.

Comment: I'm stuck with the same problem.  I'm using the "request" module but I can't seem to figure out how to enable authentication to pass through from the nodejs side of Electron.  The render requests all seem to work fine.